# Dock icons colors are messed up

Tags: dock, macos

This happens sometimes and all i can do to fix it is reboot.
Any idea why this happens?[image]

Comment: rest of the screen is OK? Does typing `killall Dock` in Terminal fix it?

Comment: The rest of the screen is okay, oddly enough. I'll try your killall dock. Thanks

Comment: That actually works, thanks! it still would be nice to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Do you notice any pattern?  Perhaps when launching an app?

Comment: I didn't link this to any app in particular but it usually happens when I wake up my computer from sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to go for the 'fix it even if it's not broken' approach...

- Fix permissions, check & if necessary repair disk, using Disk Utility
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Update to 10.10.5 using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store